# Regular expression to extract bracketed and end string

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a web app that uses scraping to harvest it's data. I have run into a roadblock in that I'm unsure on how to write a regular expression to extract the data I need.

I need to extract the distance and grade from a string like the following.

```
"The Bet with the Tote 525 (A6) 525y"
```

The grade is the "A6" and the distance is the "525y".

Every now and again, the string has another set of brackets in it that need to be ruled out. For example in this string:

```
"The Bet with the Tote (Starter race) Some more info (A6) 525y"
```

I will need the second set of brackets. The grade and distance are **always** appended to the end of the description so will always be at the end of the string.

I have tried simply using substr() to get the number of characters from the end of the string but every now and again, the distance is set to something like "525yH" which completely throws it out. For that reason, I would guess that a regular expression would be the best option.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Dan

**Extended Information**

- The grade is always a minimum of 2 characters. Maximum of 3.
- The grade does not always consist of a letter and a number.
- Examples of grades:

  - "A1" through to "A10"
  - "T1" through to "T10"
  - "OR"
  - A number of other letter/number combinations
- Distance can be in either metres or yards.
- Distance is always a 3 character integer with either "y" or "m" except:
- Sometimes the distance has a H on the end which should be ommited.

Comment: What are the possible formats for grade? Is it always 2 characters? It is always a letter follows by a number? What are the possible formats for distance? Is it always 4 character? Is it always 3 numbers and a letter? When asking for regex help please supply large enough sample size or a thorough description for us to test against.

Comment: In this case `525yH` do you want the H to match or to ignore the H?

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. I have added some extended information to answer your questions. However, after reading other answers, I think that maybe using explode delimited by spaces would be a simpler option.

Comment: The issue with the explode method is that you then need an additional test and possible operation to omit the trailing H

Comment: I have updated my answer to be less daunting thanks to your updates

Comment: I think that in the long run, it would just be easier to use the additional test and operation. In the future, I may find that the additional H is useful and need to use it. I still need to try out the explode method when I get home so could end up using a regular expression in the end. Many thanks for your detailed response though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data pattern is fixed, why not use EXPLODE ?

```
<?php

$str = "The Bet with the Tote 525 (A6) 525y";
$strArr = explode(" ",$str);
$arrCount = count($strArr);
$data1 = $strArr[$arrCount - 1];
$data2 = $strArr[$arrCount - 2];
echo $data1," , ",$data2;

?>
```

Comment: This seems like a viable alternative to using a regex. I will definately test this when I get home and let you know.

Comment: With regards to removing the H from the distance, I can use a seperate function to check if the H exists and remove it from the string.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the update question it's a simple as:

```
preg_match('/(\(\w+\)) (\w+)H?/', $str, $matches);
```

Usage:

```
$str = "The Bet with the Tote 525 (A6) 525y";

print_r($matches);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (A6) 525y
    [1] => (A6)
    [2] => 525y
)
```

or:

```
$str = "The Bet with the Tote (Starter race) Some more info (A6) 525y";

print_r($matches);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (A6) 525y
    [1] => (A6)
    [2] => 525y
)
```

**Although** I personally prefer the elegance if the explode method, it then would require and extra condition and possible operation to remove the trailing H.

Comment: You can of cause make this more flexible, but it's hard to get a good grasp of your sample strings from your question

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
([^)]+) (\d+y.?)$
```

which is a little more specific

Answer (score 1):

Since

> The grade and distance are **always**
>   appended to the end of the description
>   so will always be at the end of the
>   string.

Something like the following, without regex, might work. That is, assuming your above statement is correct.

```
$text = "The Bet with the Tote (Starter race) Some more info (A6) 525y";
array_slice(explode(" ", $text), -2, 2);

//returns
Array
(
    [0] => (A6)
    [1] => 525y
)
```

Comment: see his last point _I have tried simply using substr() to get the number of characters from the end of the string but every now and again, the distance is set to something like "525yH" which completely throws it out._

Comment: @xzyfer: Yes, thats fine. Since I'm splitting on the spaces I don't see how that would adversely affect my script ?

Comment: I read it as meaning he didn't want the last character. I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'The Bet with the Tote 525 (A6) 525y';

preg_match_all('/.*\((?P<grade>.+?)\)\s(?P<distance>.+?)$/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "(A6) 525y"
  }
  ["grade"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "A6"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "A6"
  }
  ["distance"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "525y"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "525y"
  }
}
```

So you can access the grade and distance by accessing `$matches['grade']` and `$matches['distance']`.

#### Update

Your second string...

> The Bet with the Tote (Starter race) Some more info (A6) 525y

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(61) "The Bet with the Tote (Starter race) Some more info (A6) 525y"
  }
  ["grade"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "A6"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "A6"
  }
  ["distance"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "525y"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "525y"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
/.*?\((.*?)\)\W+(.*)$/
```

Comment: Lazy evaluation may not be needed since .* at the beginning will dominate till the last parantheses.